# Dragging windows

Tags: javascript, ios

I did some research on this and still can't find a good solution for it. I wrote my app in ExtJS 4.1 and when I run it on an iPod the dragging functionality is disabled by default (which is what I want), but if I write the same app in ExtJS 6.2 all windows can be draggable which causes issues of visibility of the app. With that being said, Does anyone know how to disable window dragging when using Tablets (iPod, iPad, etc.)? I'm using ExtJS 6.2

Here's my working code that works great for a single window, but I want a general solution that will stop ALL windows from being dragged.

```
       var win = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
            title: "My Window",
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: form,
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Close',
                handler: function() {
                    win.hide();
                }
            }]
        });

        win.show();

        if(Ext.os.deviceType === 'Tablet') {
            win.dd.disable();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "global solution" sounds like you want to use an override to apply one of the other answers globally to your application:

```
Ext.define('MyAppName.override.Window', {
    override: 'Ext.window.Window',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        if(Ext.os.deviceType === 'Tablet') {
            this.dd.disable();
        }
    }
})
```

or

```
Ext.define('MyAppName.override.Window', {
    override: 'Ext.window.Window',
    initComponent: function() {
        if(Ext.os.deviceType === 'Tablet') {
            this.draggable = false;
        }
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
})
```

To make the override work, put it into the file `app/override/Window.js` and add a reference to your `requires` array in `Application.js`:

```
requires: [
    'MyAppName.override.Window'
],
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`Ext.os` class](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.os.html). 
More precisely `Ext.os.is` method, according to [the docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.os.html#method-is) it has all the values you would need.

I am not sure why you want to block only iPads and not tables in general. If you wan tablets than you can use `if(Ext.os.deviceType === 'Tablet') {...}`

Otherwise `if(Ext.os.is.iPad) {...}`.

---

**UPDATE Solution:**

If you want to force anything across all classes in the ExtJS you would use [`Ext.override`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.html#method-override).

So the solution would be to put at the beginning of the app this code:

```
if (Ext.os.deviceType === 'Tablet') {
    Ext.override('Ext.Window', {
        privates: {
            initDraggable: function(){}
        }
    })
}
```

FYI You can check the Ext.Window source code. I had to override this method, the default value `draggable: false` doesn't work.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2iqi
*To test it, just press F12 switch to table mode.*

**But this solution has 1 drawback:**

> If the target is a class declared using Ext.define, the override
>   method of that class is called

Which means this solution don't work when you use  `Ext.create('Ext.Window',{})`

Solution for that would be to define our own `Ext.Window` class and than inside the app when you are using `Ext.create('Ext.Window'` you would use `Ext.create('Fiddle.view.MyWindow',` and when we have our own function already we don't need to use override but can put if directly into the class definition like this:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.MyWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.Window',
    alias: 'widget.mywindow',

    draggable: (function(){
        if (Ext.os.deviceType === 'Tablet') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    })()

});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2iqj

I don't know how to override it for `Ext.create('Ext.Window'` if you still insists on using it. One solution would be to re-write `Ext.create` or simply edit the framework source itself but I highly discourage from that.

Comment: Actually, I want to disable dragging windows functionality in all tablets, so your answer gets me close, but I would like to do a general disabling for the whole app by disabling the draggable config as you mentioned. Do you know or have any idea how to do that? or in which file is it that I need to make the change? Can you share a sample code? I'm using ExtJS 6.2 Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add code, which component exactly(xtype) are you using and it's draggable ?

Comment: I updated my question. The code works great, but I want a general solution to STOP window dragging in the whole app. Any ideas how to make it a global solution?

Answer (score 3):

Why you are not using `draggable: false` in window config
Here is some code in [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2itb)

```
var win = Ext.create('Fiddle.view.MyWindow', {
        title: "My Window",
        width: 500,
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        layout: 'fit',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Close',
            handler: function() {
                win.hide();
            }
        }]
    });

    win.show();
```

Comment: I want a GLOBAL solution not just for a single window